# dynamic sales teams with roles

Tags: role-hierarchy, roles, visibility, teams

I need to create a certain visibility on accounts and alla their related objects in my org. Org wide defaults are now set ad private, but i need to create sales team with sales men and managers. 
Sales men should be able to view obly their accounts while managers must be able to see alla their sales men accounts but not other managers teams info.

I know I should probably be able to do this with roles and hierarchy, but then I would need to create roles for every team and that is not really dynamic (also considering having lots of teams in the future), so I am wondering, is there any way to set up this kind of visibility more dynamically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to go for Role Hierarchy setup rather than thinking around any other dynamic approach. the main reason is if you donot setup parallel hierarchies, then you might end up setting same role for Managers.
 
 The real impact here is - **Manager A** will be able to see all the accounts for **Manager B's Sales Men**. The reason is the small checkbox that resided on "sharing Setting" which is default checked and non-editable for standard objects called as **"Grant Access using Hierarchies"**. So that way you are compromising on data visibility and accessibility. 
I agree to your concern of growing teams over time but one should always account for Admin level tasks while using Salesforce CRM system. Role hierarchy setup is an Administrative task that doesnot need a developer. So while laying the OWD-architecture, account for all possible future aspects (multiple teams/multiple regions/multiple geographies) and implement the most scalable approach.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this solution and it seems to work. Also, in my case Manager A is not even able to see all the accounts for Manager B's Sales Man - even better! I dont really understand why though